# how to Filter File Browser to specific extensions on IE?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to create upload file operation so I put the following code:

```
<img src="[@spring.url '/images/buttons/upload.jpg'/]" onclick="uploadFile()" title="Upload File" />

//I want to do this without showing the input file
<div style="display: none;">
    <input id="inputFile" type="file" name="upload" accept=".txt,.csv,.zip" onchange="uploadListener();">
</div>
```

the image tag has nothig to do with the files just I don't want to show the input file so I use image instead to invoke it.

and js like this:

```
function uploadFile(){
       document.getElementById('inputFile').click();

   }

   function uploadListener(){

           alert($('#inputFile').val());
           $.ajax({
               type: "POST",
               url: "/panda/assay/designability/uploadFile.htm",
               data: {file: $('#inputFile').val()} ,
               success: function(response){

               }
           });

   }
```

this never worked to create custom filter, I found out that the "accept" attribute is not supported by IE unfortunatley I have to work with it. any suggestions??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to check this on your server. As a best practice, and especially with file upload, you should anyway do some checks server side to avoid malicious script injection/execution. It is indeed very easy to update HTML/javascript client-side to be able to upload any kind of file... I would also suggest to store your file outside your webroot, but this has nothing to do with this question...

Comment: I do that, BUT I want the user to see "just" specific files when s/he perform this operation. what file outside webroot?!!

Comment: Oh ok my bad. Then I'm affraid you just can wait for IE to implement this attribute.
And you should store the uploaded file outside your webroot so that if ever a malicious file gets uploaded, people can't launch it from the web...

Comment: The `accept` attribute on file input elements is implemented in IE10.

Comment: @RayNicholus yeah but not in any version earlier :-( IE 8 is the required explorer

Comment: @MuhammadRamahy There is no way to restrict the file types displayed in the file chooser dialog in IE9 or older due to the lack of support for the `accept` property.  You'll need to enforce file type restrictions server-side, which you should be doing anyway.